# I can't open Minecraft with Litemod (Gave up trying to download...)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I installed Minecraft Liteload 1.7.10, and when I try to open this profile, the development console give me that error:

```
(full log)
Shiginima Launcher: SE V1.602 (through bootstrap 1) started on windows...
Current time is Feb 25, 2015 10:37:14 AM
Refreshing local version list...
System.getProperty('os.name') == 'Windows 7'
System.getProperty('os.version') == '6.1'
System.getProperty('os.arch') == 'amd64'
System.getProperty('java.version') == '1.8.0_31'
System.getProperty('java.vendor') == 'Oracle Corporation'
System.getProperty('sun.arch.data.model') == '64'
Refreshing remote version list...
Refresh complete.
Loaded 5 profile(s); selected 'LiteLoader 1.8 with Forge 11.14.0.1299'
Getting syncinfo for selected version
Queueing library & version downloads
Download job 'Version & Libraries' started (16 threads, 4 files)
Attempting to download C:\Users\Emilia\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraft\launchwrapper\1.11\launchwrapper-1.11.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 0)
Attempting to download C:\Users\Emilia\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\16.0\guava-16.0.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 0)
Attempting to download C:\Users\Emilia\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm-all\5.0.3\asm-all-5.0.3.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 0)
Attempting to download C:\Users\Emilia\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.7.10-LiteLoader1.7.10\1.7.10-LiteLoader1.7.10.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 0)
Couldn't download https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/1.7.10-LiteLoader1.7.10/1.7.10-LiteLoader1.7.10.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
java.lang.RuntimeException: Server responded with 403
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.EtagDownloadable.download(EtagDownloadable.java:48)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(DownloadJob.java:112)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$000(DownloadJob.java:15)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(DownloadJob.java:94)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Delta time to compare resources: 940 ms 
Download job 'Resources' skipped as there are no files to download
Job 'Resources' finished successfully
Attempting to download C:\Users\Emilia\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.7.10-LiteLoader1.7.10\1.7.10-LiteLoader1.7.10.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 1)
Finished downloading C:\Users\Emilia\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\16.0\guava-16.0.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that
Finished downloading C:\Users\Emilia\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm-all\5.0.3\asm-all-5.0.3.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that
Finished downloading C:\Users\Emilia\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraft\launchwrapper\1.11\launchwrapper-1.11.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that
Couldn't download https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/1.7.10-LiteLoader1.7.10/1.7.10-LiteLoader1.7.10.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
java.lang.RuntimeException: Server responded with 403
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.EtagDownloadable.download(EtagDownloadable.java:48)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(DownloadJob.java:112)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$000(DownloadJob.java:15)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(DownloadJob.java:94)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Attempting to download C:\Users\Emilia\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.7.10-LiteLoader1.7.10\1.7.10-LiteLoader1.7.10.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 2)
Couldn't download https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/1.7.10-LiteLoader1.7.10/1.7.10-LiteLoader1.7.10.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
java.lang.RuntimeException: Server responded with 403
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.EtagDownloadable.download(EtagDownloadable.java:48)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(DownloadJob.java:112)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$000(DownloadJob.java:15)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(DownloadJob.java:94)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Attempting to download C:\Users\Emilia\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.7.10-LiteLoader1.7.10\1.7.10-LiteLoader1.7.10.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 3)
Couldn't download https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/1.7.10-LiteLoader1.7.10/1.7.10-LiteLoader1.7.10.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
java.lang.RuntimeException: Server responded with 403
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.EtagDownloadable.download(EtagDownloadable.java:48)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(DownloadJob.java:112)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$000(DownloadJob.java:15)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(DownloadJob.java:94)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Attempting to download C:\Users\Emilia\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.7.10-LiteLoader1.7.10\1.7.10-LiteLoader1.7.10.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 4)
Couldn't download https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/1.7.10-LiteLoader1.7.10/1.7.10-LiteLoader1.7.10.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
java.lang.RuntimeException: Server responded with 403
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.EtagDownloadable.download(EtagDownloadable.java:48)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(DownloadJob.java:112)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$000(DownloadJob.java:15)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(DownloadJob.java:94)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Attempting to download C:\Users\Emilia\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.7.10-LiteLoader1.7.10\1.7.10-LiteLoader1.7.10.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 5)
Couldn't download https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/1.7.10-LiteLoader1.7.10/1.7.10-LiteLoader1.7.10.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
java.lang.RuntimeException: Server responded with 403
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.EtagDownloadable.download(EtagDownloadable.java:48)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(DownloadJob.java:112)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$000(DownloadJob.java:15)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(DownloadJob.java:94)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Gave up trying to download https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/1.7.10-LiteLoader1.7.10/1.7.10-LiteLoader1.7.10.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
Job 'Version & Libraries' finished with 1 failure(s)!
```

As you see I use Shignima Launcher, but i tried another ones. I also deleted .minecraft folder in %appdata%, but it still give me that error. Help!

Comment: Illegal content is off-topic here on Arqade. If you have a legal Minecraft account, please provide us either with a very good reason you want to use Shiginima, or provide a crash log from the official launcher.

Comment: You have Liteloader for MC 1.7.10 and Forge for 1.8. Return to drawing board. (Also: stop using a cracked client if you want Minecraft to work reliably.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get a legal mc account so you can use the default launcher.

Second, make sure that you have installed Forge correctly, and make sure it is the correct version. `Forge 1.8 = Liteloader 1.8` and `Forge 1.7.10 = Liteloader 1.7.10`.

After making sure you have both of the files, and they are both the same version, follow what I am going to say.

1. Install Forge x.x.x first, then run Minecraft, so this way Forge can get all the files loaded without any form of complication.
2. Run `Liteloader.exe` and make sure that you choose an option that is close to saying either Zip or Jar.
3. Drag the jar file that you will find into the Mods folder.
4. Start the Launcher that you choose to use, and then start Minecraft. It should all run perfectly fine. But be warned, some mods will break with each other due to Liteloader and Forge mixing, as it has happened to me before.